# Padding inside an input without affect the width

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, materialize

i'm getting problems with padding the content of the input.
this is how i see an input without adding nothing:

[image: image without padding]

i want to put a padding in the `placeholder` and the content `value`, when i try to add a:

```
input{
    padding-left: 10px;
}
```

this happends:

[image: image with padding:10px]

like you can see:

1. the `textarea` have the 100% of the width, but adding the padding to the inputs make them get over the max width.
2. when i have two inputs in a same row, they overlaps each other.

i tried changin the `width` of each one of the inputs with percentages to get something that looks good, but it becomes a problem when the screen's size change and becomes responsive.

so, i tried another solution; i change the padding and the resizing, for this:

```
::-webkit-input-placeholder { 
    padding-left: 10px;
}

:-moz-placeholder { /* Firefox 18- */
    color: grey; 
    padding-left: 10px;
}

::-moz-placeholder {  /* Firefox 19+ */
    padding-left: 10px; 
}

:-ms-input-placeholder {
    padding-left: 10px; 
}
```

but now, i have another problem, that solve partialy my problem, beacuse, this add a padding, but only to the `placeholder` not to the content `value`.

[image]

how can i solve my problem? any idea?

Comment: Use `box-sizing: border-box`. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/box-sizing

Comment: Can you post your code and create a demo of the problem?

Comment: The Head Rush's solution works. Just to be clear, add the property to the input element.

Comment: No it doesn't work. Didn't change anything

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can change the way the box model is calculated by using the `box-sizing` property.

http://www.paulirish.com/2012/box-sizing-border-box-ftw/

This way you add the padding to the inputs themselves and not the placeholder text. More consistant.